# UIImagePickerController StatusBar to White Colour

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I am trying to change `UIImagePickerController` statusBar colour to white and i succeed to set White StatusBar with below Code.

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = YES

-(UIViewController*)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle {
    return nil;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

**ScreenShots**

[image: 1st Image]

[image: 2nd Image]

[image: 3rd Image]

[image: 4th Image]

**ISSUE**

when i present `UIImagePickerController`, the status bar is white **(1st Image)** than i select one of album, it will display all video list **(2nd Image)** & than i click on particular video, it will show video preview **(3rd Image)**.

when i press **"Cancel"** button from Video Preview, it pop to all Video list **(2nd Screen)** **(but the status bar becomes black)**

how to set status bar white?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not to implement extension of `UIImagePickerController` and put `-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}` in the extension?

Comment: @FahriAzimov : Thanks man,I create an extension of UIImagePickerController and add preferredStatusBarStyle in it and it works.

Comment: You are welcome! I will add this as answer, please accept it if the solution solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement extension of the `UIImagePickerController` and add

`-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}`

to the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Please add in info.plist

View controller-based status bar appearance And
Status bar style

[image]

Comment: It will hide status bar in All Viewcontroller but i don't want to do that.

Comment: ok @Kuldeep You set View controller-based status bar appearance = YES You set it to NO

Comment: when i set  View controller-based status bar appearance = no i will hide status bar in All ViewController.